# Indian traveling to Thailand with residence in Europe

Tags: visas, thailand, tourist-visas

I'd like to visit Thailand with my wife. I get a visa exemption for 30 days, but she only gets VoA for 15 days, which is annoying. Apparently there's a special rule for Indians with residence outside of India. Does anyone have further information on that?

**Update:**

The embassy in Phnom Penh refused to take the application and said we need to apply from India or a country we reside in. Had to cancel all flights and hotels booked in order to complete the application. Not happy about the situation, 15 days in Thailand isn't worth the trouble getting there and out.

Comment: I've never heard of a "special rule" for VoA. There are 21 countries eligible for VoA, and there are no exceptions, residence-based or otherwise. Note that the VoA queue can be a nice circus, depending on the time of arrival, what with the groups of Chinese and Indian tourists.

Comment: How many days will you (or her) intend to stay in Thailand?

Comment: We were going for the regular 30 days that I normally get on arrival, but I guess we'll both go for the visa now and go for 60 instead, to make it worth the trouble.

Comment: And what is the country of your passport?  What about your wife's country of residence?  How often do you/your wife intend to go to thailand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "special rule" may be referring to the fact that **a resident of a country can apply at a Thai Embassy, official Consulate, or possibly an honorary consulate in the country of their residence.**  You do *not* have to travel or send passport back to India and visit Thai Embassy there.

I would recommend getting a minimum SETV vs VoA.  VoAs are only good for 14 days and ***cannot*** be extended at local immigration.  And she cannot do a border hop "Out-In" in most cases.  She would need to fly out *and* fly back in (Kuala Lumpur or maybe India) to do another VoA.

A SETV would give her 60 days + option to extend at local immigration office for 30 days.

It's "special" because normally certain countries must apply for visa in their home countries only (usually countries with high migrant risk and no easy deportation option).  Not saying it's fair, but it seems most developed countries do this on some level.

Comment: Indeed you can apply where you live (and need to show proof of it). But it is not for Indians only [as hinted by the OP in his question]. Upvoted.

Comment: Thanks. Does that mean I can't just walk into any Thai embassy anywhere and apply for a visa? We're currently in Cambodia and were planning to head to Phnom Penh for the visa application.

Comment: @patrick, That is correct.  You never mentioned your passport country, or your wife's residence country. Certain restricted countries you must apply in home country or country of residence.  You are welcome to go anyway and see what they say.  Or overstay and then just pay the fine when you leave (500 baht/day  20k max).  Do tell us what the outcome is.

Comment: The embassy refused to take the application and said we need to apply from India. Had to cancel all flights and hotels booked in order to complete the application. Not happy about the situation, 15 days in Thailand isn't worth the visit.